# unexpected outcome of data.table fintersect all = TRUE

Tags: r, data.table, set

## Set operations for data tables

The amazing data.table package contains [Set operations for data tables](https://rdatatable.gitlab.io/data.table/reference/setops.html). The examples given in the documentation contain datatables with only one column. In order to understand their behaviour and difference with base R set operations I extended the tables with another column. This resulted in an unexpected outcome, which might be due to my understanding, it might also be a bug which I will raise if the stackoverflow community agrees.

### Example 1, with expected outcome

The following example shows the expected behaviour when we use the default setting for parameter `all` set to `FALSE`

```
library(data.table)

(DT <- 
    data.table(
      x = c(1, 2, 2, 2),
      y = LETTERS[c(1, 2, 2, 3)]
    )
)
```

> ```
>    x y
> 1: 1 A
> 2: 2 B
> 3: 2 B
> 4: 2 C
> ```

```
data.table::fintersect(DT, DT, all = FALSE)
```

> ```
>    x y
> 1: 1 A
> 2: 2 B
> 3: 2 C
> ```

### Example 2, with unexpected outcome

The following example shows the **unexpected** behaviour when we don't use the default setting for parameter `all` but set it to `TRUE`

```
library(data.table)

(DT <- 
    data.table(
      x = c(1, 2, 2, 2),
      y = LETTERS[c(1, 2, 2, 3)]
    )
)
```

> ```
>    x y
> 1: 1 A
> 2: 2 B
> 3: 2 B
> 4: 2 C
> ```

```
data.table::fintersect(DT, DT, all = TRUE)
```

> ```
>    x y
> 1: 1 A
> 2: 2 B
> 3: 2 B
> ```

Expected Outcome

> ```
>    x y
> 1: 1 A
> 2: 2 B
> 3: 2 B
> 4: 2 C
> ```

### Analysis

The implementation of data.table::fintersect can be found on Git as found by a [commit of jangorecki committed on 6 Mar 2016](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/commit/5fafcc9273dc8247a29725a01305363e37d558fb?branch=5fafcc9273dc8247a29725a01305363e37d558fb)

[image]

Reproducing this function in R-code gives the expected outcome

```
DT1 <-  copy(DT)[, ".seqn" := rowidv(DT)]
DT2 <-  copy(DT)[, ".seqn" := rowidv(DT)]
DT1[DT2, .SD, .SDcols=setdiff(names(DT1),".seqn"), nomatch=0L, on=names(DT1)]
```

> ```
>    x y
> 1: 1 A
> 2: 2 B
> 3: 2 B
> 4: 2 C
> ```

## Question

As this function exists for many years I would be surprised if this is a bug, probabaly my understanding is wrong. It might be due to my R-version or other dependencies (see sessionInfo() below)
What should be the behaviour?

### SessionInfo

```
R version 4.0.5 (2021-03-31)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19043)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Dutch_Netherlands.1252  LC_CTYPE=Dutch_Netherlands.1252    LC_MONETARY=Dutch_Netherlands.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                       LC_TIME=Dutch_Netherlands.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] data.table_1.14.2

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] compiler_4.0.5  fastmap_1.1.0   htmltools_0.5.2 tools_4.0.5     yaml_2.2.1      rmarkdown_2.10  knitr_1.33      xfun_0.25      
 [9] digest_0.6.27   rlang_0.4.11    evaluate_0.14
```

Comment: You should report as a bug on the issue tracker. It's related to naming conflicts. The function uses `x` and `y` as the names of the data.tables. You also happen to have columns named `x` and `y`. So in the function, `x[, ".seqn" := rowid(x)]`, in your example, data.table is using `rowid(x)` on the vector as opposed to the whole data.table. If you change your vectors to `x1` and `y1` (or change your data table names to `DT1` as in your working example), it works. A potential solution for the maintainers is to change the names of `x` and `y` to `.x` and `.y` or something to reduce likelihood.

Comment: Many thanks Cole, I raised a [bug](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/5255)

Answer (score 1):

### Example 3, with expected outcome and ALL = TRUE

The answer of [Cole](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11355066/cole) is indeed the root cause, many thanks. I will raise a bug.

Below the working example based on the comments

```
library(data.table)

(DT <- 
    data.table(
      x1 = c(1, 2, 2, 2),
      y1 = LETTERS[c(1, 2, 2, 3)]
    )
) 

   x1 y1
1:  1  A
2:  2  B
3:  2  B
4:  2  C

data.table::fintersect(DT, DT, all = TRUE)  

   x1 y1
1:  1  A
2:  2  B
3:  2  B
4:  2  C
```